# C# datagrid each column width based on percent of total? asp.net

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

I have a DataGrid that's being populated with the code below, the code below makes the overall grid the size I want but it does set the column width.  What I want to do is be able to say hey there is 'x' columns in a datatable and my tablewidth is 'xInt' divide xint by 'x' columns (which i've done, i'm just not sure have to set the column width...)

Thanks!

```
    int tableWidth = 650;
    int columnCount = dtTable.Columns.Count;
    int columnWidth = Math.Abs(tableWidth / columnCount);
    SupportContacts.ItemStyle.Wrap = true;
    SupportContacts.Width = tableWidth;
    SupportContacts.DataSource = dtTable;
    SupportContacts.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following (although I'm not sure if it will let you when you are auto-generating your columns).

```
foreach( DataGridColumn c in SupportContacts.Columns)
{
    c.ItemStyle.Width = Unit.Point(columnWidth);
}
```